# Inserting rows in an Excel table error message

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tables. If I copy rows of data from another area and try to insert the data into the table, I get this message:

```
This operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells   
in a table on your worksheet.
```

If I insert less rows then what is between the tables is fine.  Everything shifts down. If the number of rows exceeds the number of rows between the tables I get the message.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: It's possible @Doug Glancy answered this [here](http://superuser.com/questions/417196/cant-insert-cells-in-excel-2010-operation-not-allowed-error-message?rq=1). Try the answer he provided and see if it helps.